# Python GUI for running shell scripts on the file user selects

Tags: python, user-interface

I need to create a gui in python where in the gui has a browse button and i need to run specific shell scripts on those browsed files. Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: Can you show us anything you've tried to implement to achieve this result?  StackOverflow is _not_ a code writing service.

Comment: Use Tkinter and [`tkFileDialog.askopenfile`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog).

Comment: I think I've seen something like this on the web somewhere, have a good look, and give it a go (we won't write it for you).

Comment: Without narrowing the scope of your question I feel this is too broad for SO. If you focused your question specifically on the part of this task you are having trouble with, then you would probably fare better.

Comment: I have started to write the code using the tkinter module... i just wanted to know how to display the output of a particular script.(i am running the script on the file user selects, which in turn produces another file)

Answer (score 0):

```
import wx,os
a = wx.App()
d = wx.FileDialog(None,"Select A Script",wildcard="*.py")
d.ShowModal()
os.system(d.GetPath())
```

4 actual lines of code... you could have easily googled this ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. But actually, i have started using the tkinter module for my gui. And one more thing is that the user has to select the file on which the shell script has to run. And the output should be displayed on a new window.